# how to display an array with in a `$_SESSION[]` variable using `echo` statement

Tags: php

i want to use echo statement:

```
$_SESSION['uname']=array('ashis','samir','tku','abcd');

echo $_SESSION['uname'][0];
```

i know it sholud be display with

`print_r($_SESSION['uname'])`

but i want to use `echo` statement.

Any help wil be greatfull.

Comment: have you listened about `for` or `foreach` loop?

Comment: So what you get when you execute `echo $_SESSION['uname'][0];`?

Comment: Yes @u_mulder i like to display the element with its index number.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question, try this one:

```
$_SESSION['uname'] = array('ashis', 'samir', 'tku', 'abcd');
foreach ($_SESSION["uname"] as $name) {
    echo $name ."<br />\n";
}
```

It will display:

```
ashis<br />
samir<br />
tku<br />
abcd<br />
```

Comment: it will work but i want to display with its index number like $_SESSION['uname'][0]; or $_SESSION['uname'][1]; is it possible? @lolka_bolka

Comment: Yes, but why don't you just do what you want? `echo $_SESSION['uname'][0];`

Comment: ya i need to use this because i want to store an array with in a session varible and insert that value in a database in an another page.@lolka_bolka